# Visual Studio error : General exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, visual-studio-2015, project

I have a new exception while creating a new project (any project) through vs 2015. It says

```
General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
```

At first I tried to install jetbrains resharper using nuget package manager. And it was not installed properly. I was using GIT source control. So I reverted back the changes made to the project.

I've been facing this issue since then. I've uninstalled and reinstalled vs 2015. Though I was facing the same issue.

When I searched for the issue, I found that I can request for the hot fixes from msdn and did so. But it didn't correctly worked solving my issue.

The following are the screenshots about the issue I'm facing.

[image: While creating a new project]

[image: No project is created]

Any help from anyone will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.